# Can't select object in edit mode

Tags: uv, objects, particles, edit-mode

So I am a beginner in blender and trying to make a tree with sapling tool. I made it, added texture on leaves and I wanted to do the same to the bark but I faced a problem. When I want to select bark in edit mode to unwrap it, I can't. I only see these particles, these threads. 
Do you have an idea how to transform the bark into an object and unwrap it?

[image: My tree in edit mode]

Comment: Ctrl +tab thats it, then choose vertice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tree's bark is a beveled curve, not a mesh object. You have to convert it first. Select the tree in object mode and hit alt+c then select curve to mesh. After you can unwrap it.

Comment: Thank you so much!